# Understanding jQuery-Mobile page firing events - why dialog pageshows when closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

I'm relatively new to jQuery-Mobile and I'm trying to understand what's happening when a page or dialog loads.

I created a small set of files to illustrate the oddity I'm seeing.
Please see https://github.com/kanesee/jqm-event

The simple example just has an index page that prints Hello World. There's a button that opens a dialog, by opening another page, called dialog.html. I print out whenever either page fires a pageshow or pagehide event.

This is the sequence of actions.

1. Open index.html: (index's pageshow fires as expected)
2. Click on dialog link and dialog pops up: (then this sequence of events fire: index pagehide, dialog pagehide, index pageshow, dialog pageshow)
3. Close dialog: (index pagehide, dialog pagehide, index pageshow, dialog pageshow)

I don't understand why when the dialog opens, that sequence fires. I understand index pagehide since we're transitioning out of the index page. Not sure why the dialog's pagehide fires next. Not sure why index's pageshow fires. I understand why dialog's pageshow fires last.

I also don't understand why the sequence fires during dialog close. Not sure why index's pagehide fires. I understand why dialog pagehide fires and then why index pageshow fires. Not sure why dialog pageshow fires again at the end.

If anyone can help explain this odd sequence of events, I'd appreciate it.
I've looked at this sequence diagram but I'm not sure I fully understand it: http://bradbroulik.blogspot.co.nz/2011/12/jquery-mobile-events-diagram.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because `pageshow` and `pagehide` will fire on any page. In your code you haven't delegated the event to neither index or dialog. Those events are bound to *document*, so will fire on all pages to come.

If you do the below, you'll notice the difference.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#index", function () {
  console.log("Page is shown");
});
```

It will only fire on index page (with `id="index"`) when it is visible.

---

### Update

In your code, you haven't attached `pageshow` and `pagehide` to specific pages. Both events fire on `data-role="page"` and `data-role="dialog"` when they are either visible or hidden.

In index.html, you have the below code.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#indexpage', function(event) {
  console.log('pageshow index.html');
});

$(document).on('pagehide', '#indexpage', function(event) {
  console.log('pagehide index.html');
});
```

On start-up, console log will print

> pageshow index.html

When you move from index.html to dialog.html (via Ajax), console log will print

> pagehide index.html

But before console log prints `pagehide index.html`, the below code in dialog.html is loaded into DOM along with HTML and executed.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#dialogPage', function(event) {
  console.log('pageshow dialog.html');
});

$(document).on('pagehide', '#dialogPage', function(event) {
  console.log('pagehide dialog.html');
});
```

Therefore, `pagehide` will fire twice when moving from index.html to dialog.html. Also, it will fire twice when moving from dialog.html back to index.html. At this moment, `pageshow` will fire twice as well.

Console log will print the following:

1. Start-up

   > pageshow index.html
2. From index.html to dialog.html

   > pagehide index.html ->
   >   pagehide dialog.html ->
   >   pageshow index.html ->
   >   pageshow dialog.html
3. From dialog.html to index.html

   > pagehide index.html ->
   >   pagehide dialog.html ->
   >   pageshow index.html ->
   >   pageshow dialog.html

#### Solution:

Be specific when using `pagebeforehide`, `pagebeforeshow`, `pagehide` and `pageshow` events

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#pageID", function () {
  /* do something */
});
```

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you. I was racking my brain over this all night.

Comment: Just a note to others who see this answer. In the above answer, make sure you add an id to the page container div like so:
<div data-role="page" id="index">
Same for dialog page

Comment: @kane you're welcome. If you want, I can elaborate more on my answer. I wrote it in a hurry.

Comment: I think I'm good. But if you elaborate, it might help others who come upon this same problem. I'm sure it'll be rewarded with more upvotes

Comment: I researched a lot and even on the jqm site I found this solution. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Guttemberg Thank you :) The answer is outdated, please refer to this: https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/